# Ideas how to query two collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have collection **friends**

```
- userId: user id
- Friends: array of user ids
```

And **users**

```
- _id: userId
- Last Login
- Other User info fields
```

Last login field is updated every 5 minutes if user is browsing my website.

Right now I have logic where I get user ids from friends from **friend** collection, then query **user** collection with that ids to get user info.

ADDED: In addition in future releases i would add that user will be able to add friends not only users but pets from other collection so friend embedded array will look like {UserId, PetId}

But for next release I would like to add new functionality where I would show friends sorted by last login.

Solutions which I think would work

1. Map reduce on select -Easy to implement but would probably have problems with performance
2. Map reduce on update - in this case i would probably use property "out" to write new collection on each update, so then i will have new collection **Friend.reduced** with all info i need, and then i can easy query it by indexes
3. Add new property Last Update to Friends list collection so it will look like {FriendId, LastUpdate} logic would be easy to implement on Business level.

What other options to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And simple query like below won't work?

```
var someId = ObjectId("52758653cbd6ca816ca0ee1b")
var friends = db.friends.findOne({"userId": someId}, {"_id": 0, "friends": 1}).friends

db.users.find(
    {_id: {$in: friends }}
).sort({lastLogin: -1})
```

Comment: Well its also and idea, but the most complex thing is that in my project friends are not only users :) they will be also pets. :)

Comment: Well i just thought but probably this solution would work, because pet has owner and this owner is user id, so Friends array will have object {UserId, PetId - this would be nullable} then i can easy sort, and still if friend was added as pet, i will get info about pet.

Comment: Could you add some details to the question. It really looks like a job for a simple query and it is not clear why do you want map-reduce.

Comment: Done and yes you are right its possible to do with two queries, get all ids, then using that ids i can sort User collection and rest will do in my code.

Comment: I have one more question, how is that possible to do request in some thing like Stored Procedure? I have read about eval and javascript function but both have limitations or not recommended. Because in my case i am doing request which returns lets say 100 user ids and then second request, so my concern is what will be if i have 1000 or more friends it will probably have some impact on performance...

Comment: Personally I would handle that inside your application, but it is hard to say more without some background. I suggest you ask separate question where you provide relevant details.